# Checking if a set is a field

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, field-theory

I had a question where it asked whether $\mathbb{Z}_9$ was a field. I was given a vague explanation  by my professor and I know it has something to do with the fact I can split $9$ into $3\times3$. And since in field $a\times b = 0$ and where either $a = 0$ or $b = 0$ but since $3\times3\neq 0$ it can't be a field. I don't quite understand where this law comes from. Any clarification could be really helpful because this is my first week of Linear Algebra II and I'm already confused. Thanks!

Comment: There is a field with 9 elements, but it is not the integers mod 9, and your professor was probably hesitating about how much to tell you.  His argument that $\mathbb Z_9$ is not a field because $3\times3=9=0$ provides an example of a non-zero element without a multiplicative inverse, which is a total no-no in a field, is of course correct.

Comment: Algebraic answer: The ring $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$ is a field if and only if $n$ is a prime because only then any element has a multiplicative inverse. A field extension $\Bbb K\supset \Bbb F_p$ with finite field $\Bbb K$ is of finite dimension, say $d$. This implies that there are $p^d$ elements in $\Bbb K$. So what to do? Take your field $\Bbb F_3$. Look at the vector space of dimension two over this field and try to install a field structure.

Answer (score 2):

In a field, every element $a$ (except $0$) has an inverse $a^{-1}$ with respect to multiplication. That is, $a\times a^{-1}=a^{-1}\times a=1$. But then, if $a\times b=0$, then $a=0$ or $b=0$. Indeed, if $a\neq0$, then$$b=1\times b=(a^{-1}\times a)\times b=a^{-1}\times(a\times b)=a^{-1}\times0=0.$$By the same argument, if $b\neq0$, then $a=0$.

But, in $\mathbb{Z}_9$, $3\times3=0$, in spite of the fact that $3\neq0$. Therefore, $\mathbb{Z}_9$ is not a field.

Comment: Would this apply to every  $\mathbb{Z}_n$ where n is not a prime?

Comment: @SafderAree Yes. It is exactly the same argument.

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I understand it now.

Comment: @SafderAree Would you please tell me why did you unaccept my answer? It's not the first time that that happens to me, but in all previous cases that was because a better answer appeared. That's clearly not the case here.